# найти все следующие значения из списка при нахождении подстроки начиная со второго совпадения

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
str_1 = ['hdi', 'quy', 'f', 'hdi', 'djk', '4', 'hdi', '3','hdi']
str_2 = 'hdi'
secondPos = str_1.index(str_2, str_1.index(str_2) + len(str_2), 
len(str_1))
print(str_1[secondPos - 1:secondPos])
```

программа должна вывести f43, сейчас прога находит только второе совпадения - как сделать чтоб находила все начиная со второго совпадения ?

Comment: что такое f43? И почему программа должна его вывести?

Comment: я все равно не понимаю что такое f43. У вас нет никакого f43 в строке. И что такое "следующие значения" тоже не понимаю? Все буквы из строки после второго вхождения?

Comment: ок, а что такое f43?

Comment: "все символы при нахождении совпадений подстроки начиная со второго совпадения" - это в вашей строке `djkfhgjhdfqiewf8234fhioh3f49f234hdijdblqclecqec23hdi`

Comment: что такое `f43`? Нет такого сочетания символов в вашей исходной строке, ни в начале ни в конце, ни до `hdi`, ни после. Но я не понимаю, честно. Что нужно сделать?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сначала разделить строку на список по разделителю `hdi', а потом взять последюю букву из каждой части, если она есть:

```py
str_1 = 'hdiquyqgeorgfquegfhdidjkfhgjhdfqiewf8234fhioh3f49f234hdijdblqclecqec23hdi'
sep = 'hdi'

result = ''.join([part[-1] for part in str_1.split(sep) if part])
print(result)
```

Второй способ - использовать регулярные выражения:

```py
import re

str_1 = 'hdiquyqgeorgfquegfhdidjkfhgjhdfqiewf8234fhioh3f49f234hdijdblqclecqec23hdi'

result = ''.join(re.findall(r'(.)hdi', str_1))
print(result)
```

P.S. Ваш вопрос очень непонятно сформулирован. Вы хотели найти один символ перед каждым вхождением и объединить все найденные символы в общую строку.

Comment: спасибо щас попробую - сам напарил - код уже изменил - там уже массив!

Comment: спасибо работает))